# Segmentation Fault - Linked List

Tags: c, list, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am learning how to build linked lists in *C*. My program compiles but for some reason I cannot figure out, I am getting a *segmentation fault*. I've been trying to figure out the problem for a while, but I am not having any luck. Here is the faulty code:

```
int len()
{
    struct list * current = head;
    int length = 0; 

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        length++;
        current = current -> next; //move to next node
    }
    return length; 
}


struct list * search ( int key)
{
    struct list * current = head;

    while (current != NULL && current->data != key)
        current = current -> next;

    if (current != NULL && current -> data == key)
        return current;
    return NULL;
}



/* Insert a new data element with key d into the end of the list. */
void insert(int d )  //  at the end
{
    struct list * current = head; 
    struct list * new;
    while (current -> next != NULL)
        current = current -> next;
    new = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    new -> data = d; 
    current -> next = new;
    new -> next = NULL;     
}


void insertAfter(int d, int where )  //  insert at the middle
{
    struct list * marker = head;
    struct list * new;

    while(marker -> data != where)
        marker = marker -> next;
    new = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));

    new -> next = marker -> next; 
    marker -> next = new;
    new -> data = d; 
}


/* Remove the node with value d from the list */
/* assume no duplicated keys in the list */
/* If the list is empty, call prtError() to display an error message and return -1. */

void delete(int d)
{
    struct list * current1 = head; 
    struct list * current2;

    if (len() == 0)
    { //prtError("empty");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (head -> data == d)
    { 
        head = head -> next;
    }

    //Check if last node contains element
    while (current1->next->next != NULL)
        current1 = current1->next;

    if(current1->next->data == d)
            current1->next == NULL; 


    current1 = head; //move current1 back to front */

    while(current1 -> next -> data != d)
        current1 = current1 -> next; 

    current2 = current1 -> next;
    current1 -> next = current2 -> next; 

}
```

I am getting a *segmentation fault* in the delete method at the line:

```
while(current1 -> next -> data != d)
```

Why is this wrong?

Comment: In which function are you getting the segmentation fault?

Comment: If you run it in a debugger, where does the debugger say that the segmentation fault is happening?

Comment: I don't think `new` is reserved in C but you probably should not be using it as variable name. Your `delete` function looks like the likely candidate, you have `if (head -> data == d)` w/o checking for `NULL` and `current1->next->next` is probably not good either and `insert` has `current -> next` w/o a `NULL` check.

Comment: Segmentation fault occurs in the insert method - whole(current -> next != NULL)

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues, in `insert`:

```
while (current -> next != NULL)
```

you are not checking if `current` is `NULL`. There are similar issues in `delete`:

```
if (head -> data == d)
```

you need to check `head` here and:

```
while (current1->next->next != NULL)
```

is also a problem.

Comment: There is another problem at "current -> next = new;" in the insert method. What is wrong with this line? This is my first attempt at Linked Lists in C I am still learning!

Comment: @Sophie This line `while(current->next != NULL) current = current->next;` will insure that `current` is `NULL`

Comment: I am getting a segmentation fault in the delete method at the line: while(current1 -> next -> data != d)

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with the code that you post, but your mention in your comments you are concerned about `insert()`. The reason it crashes is that you will dereference a NULL pointer if `head` is NULL when `insert()` is called.

You will need a special case to insert at the `head` when it is NULL:

```
if (head) {
    while (current -> next != NULL)
        current = current -> next;
}
new = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
new -> data = d;
if (current) {
    current -> next = new;
} else {
    head = new;
}
new -> next = NULL;
```

You should check for similar issues in your other functions. Use your `search()` function as an example of avoiding dereferencing a NULL pointer in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in insert after in that you will overrun the end of the list the element is not found.

Answer (score 0):

In `insert`,

```
while(current->next != NULL) current = current->next;
```

This will guarantee that `current == NULL`.

```
current->next = new;
```

Crashes it every time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's in `insertAfter`:

```c
while(marker -> data != where)
    marker = marker -> next;
```

If no node with `data == where` is found, `marker` will be a `NULL` pointer.
The `NULL` pointer is dereferenced later in your code:

```c
new = marker -> next;
```

It makes a segfault. Checking if `marker->next != NULL` should avoid that:

```c
while(marker->next != NULL && marker -> data != where)
    marker = marker -> next;
```

But you should try to compile your program with debugging symbols (`-g` option) and run it line-by-line in a debugger like GDB.